# Reference request: "'Holds water' doesn't hold water"

Tags: calculus, reference-request

While preparing for a Calculus I course, I was recently discussing with a colleague the proper treatment of concavity in the absence of differentiability, and was reminded of an old article—in, I thought, the *American Mathematical Monthly*, but maybe it was in *Mathematics Magazine* or a similar journal—that I thought was titled, but that may just have contained the sentence, “‘Holds water’ doesn't hold water” (referring to the classical description of a curve that is concave up as one whose graph holds water).

[Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22holds+water+doesn%27t+hold+water%22) and [MathSciNet](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?pg6=ALLF&s6=%22holds%20water%22) turn up no relevant results.  Can you help?